# Linq Anonymous Types with list objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I am new to LINQ and Entity Framework, so far I have only been able to perform relatively simple data queries.  I have just begun querying data and storing the results in a class using code such as:

```
public class myData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id {get; set;}
}

 var data = (from t1 in MyContext.Table1
             from t2 in MyContext.Table2
             where t1.Id == "1"
             select new myData
             {
                 name = t1.Name,
                 id = t2.id
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is it possible to also grab data that follows many-to-one relationships?  For instance, if have many "datavalues" stored using t1.Id can query this data at the same time?

e.g.

```
public class myData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id {get; set;}
    public List<double> data {get; set;}
}

 var data = (from t1 in MyContext.Table1
             from t2 in MyContext.Table2
             where t1.Id == "1"
             select new myData
             {
                 name = t1.Name,
                 id = t2.id
                 data = t2.datavalues      <== This obviously gives a conversion error
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

It seems like there should be a reasonable way to solve this, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What's the element type of `MyContext.Table2`, and what does that type look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to `Join` the tables:

```
var query = from t1 in MyContext.Table1
    join t2 in MyContext.Table2
    on t1.Id == t2.Id into t2Values
    select new myData
    {
        name = t1.Name,
        id = t1.id,
        data = t2Values.Select(t2 => t2.SomeField),
    };
```

Comment: I also had to change my class object from List<double> data, to IEnumerable data.